# How to use Android Kotlin Dagger 2 and Firebase Auth in Data module?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, dagger-2, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to set up an app where `data` module is a library and `presentation` layer is the actual android app.  Ideally I want the `firebase` dependency to just live in the `data` module however `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` can only be called from the `presentation` module.

Putting dagger 2 and firebase dependency together gives me the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':presentation:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Removing the firebase auth dependency or dagger 2 dependency resolves this issue.  **How can I use both of these libraries together in the `data` module?**

My build.gradle for `data`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha9-1"

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
}
```

And build.gradle for presentation:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


    android {

        def configs = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")

        compileSdkVersion configs["compileSdkVersion"]
        buildToolsVersion configs["buildToolsVersion"]
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId configs["androidApplicationId"]
            minSdkVersion configs["minSdkVersion"]
            targetSdkVersion configs["targetSdkVersion"]
            versionCode configs["versionCode"]
            versionName configs["versionName"]
            testInstrumentationRunner configs["testInstrumentationRunner"]
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation project(':data')
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
        androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion", {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the top level build file (if needed)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    ext {
        //Android
        androidApplicationId = 'com.test.myapp'
        minSdkVersion = 19
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"

        //Libraries
        supportLibraryVersion = '26.1.0'

        //Testing
        testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        junitVersion = "4.12"
        espressoVersion = "3.0.1"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was with the google-services version.  The issue resolved for me after I updated the play services version:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

from `3.1.0`